# how to resolve lateinit property chargeSessionRepo has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger

in a class which extends BroadcasrReceiver, I want to access a repository function.
I get an error `lateinit property chargeSessionRepo has not been initialized`.

I have specified @Inject, what else needs to be done, so I can access the function in `ChargeSessionRepository`

```
class CustomNotificationListener : BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Inject
        lateinit var chargeSessionRepo: ChargeSessionRepository

        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            Log.d("fcmService", "onReceive ${intent.getStringExtra("onClickListener")}")
            when(intent.getStringExtra("onClickListener")) {
                "approve" -> {
                    approvePlugin(true)
                }
                "deny" -> {
                    approvePlugin(false)
                }
            }
        }

        private fun approvePlugin(isApproved: Boolean) {
            GlobalScope.launch {
                try {
                    val chargeStatusUpdate = chargeSessionRepo.getChargeStatusUpdate().data
                    val chargeStatus = chargeStatusUpdate?.firstOrNull()

                    chargeStatus?.sessionId?.let {
                        chargeSessionRepo.approvePlugIn(it, isApproved)
                    }
                } catch (exception: Exception) {
                    Log.d("fcmService", "exception: ${exception}") // lateinit property chargeSessionRepo has not been initialized
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

ChargesessionRepository

```
@Singleton
class ChargeSessionRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val chargeSessionService: ChargeSessionService,
    private val chargeSessionDao: ChargeSessionDao

) : Repository() {

    var lastChargeStatus: List<ChargeStatusDTO>? = null
        private set

    suspend fun getChargeStatusUpdate(): Resource<List<ChargeStatusDTO>> {
        val resource = getResource { chargeSessionService.getChargeStatus() }
        lastChargeStatus = resource.data

        return resource
    }
}
```

could you please suggest how to do this

Thanks
R

Comment: If you are using Dagger without Hilt you can use `DaggerBroadcastReceiver`. And Google how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You may have forgotten to put `@AndroidEntryPoint`on top of your broadcast receiver. if you are using hilt.

Comment: Hello, I am unable to add it, it does not recognise it, `class CustomNotificationListener`  is within FcmService. I tried adding @AndroidEntryPoint on top of FcmService that too did not work, android does not recognise it

class FcmService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

Comment: see this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#not-supported)